# HP EliteBook 840 G3 Audio No Device

Tags: sound, devices

This is a fesh installation on a HP Elitebook 840-G3.

```
Operating System: Kubuntu 20.04
KDE Plasma Version: 5.18.5
KDE Frameworks Version: 5.68.0
Qt Version: 5.12.8
Kernel Version: 5.11.0-41-generic
OS Type: 64-bit
Processors: 4 × Intel® Core™ i5-6300U CPU @ 2.40GHz
Memory: 15.5 GiB of RAM
```

There is no audio device detected.

I am complete newbie and really don't know what I'm doing here, but I'm following all the suggestions I can find searching this fault
It looks like the driver and the device are not meeting up. I know the device works under windows so I'm pretty sure the hardware is not at fault. Here's some of what I have tried...

`lspci -nnk | grep -A3 Audio` returns nothing

`lsmod | grep snd_hda_intel` returns nothing

`sudo apt purge timidity-daemon` reports timidity not installed

`sudo apt-get install --reinstall alsa-base pulseaudio` makes no difference

`sudo alsa force-reload` This one gives some information: `Unloading ALSA sound driver modules -NONE LOADED-` then it says `Loading ALSA...(None to reload)`

`sudo apt-get --purge remove linux-sound-base alsa-base alsa-utils` worked, then reload

`sudo apt-get install linux-sound-base alsa-base alsa-utils`

FINALLY got this:
`inxi -SMA`

```
System:
  Host: HP-EB-G3 Kernel: 5.11.0-41-generic x86_64 bits: 64 
  Desktop: KDE Plasma 5.18.5 
  Distro: Ubuntu 20.04.3 LTS (Focal Fossa) 
Machine:
  Type: Laptop System: HP product: HP EliteBook 840 G3 v: N/A 
  serial: <superuser/root required> 
  Mobo: HP model: 8079 v: KBC Version 85.79 
  serial: <superuser/root required> UEFI: HP v: N75 Ver. 01.47 
  date: 04/27/2020 
Audio: Message: No Device data found.
```

PS

I tried `aplay -l`

which returns:

`aplay: device_list:276 no soundcard found....`

Comment: Welcome to Ask Ubuntu. As Nmath says, we’ll need some more information. Have a look at the help pages to get started: https://askubuntu.com/help/on-topic

Comment: I have tried to fix the formatting in your post to get rid of the ambiguities caused by lack of formatting and no line breaks.  In the future please format commands in `monospace` and when you give the output of commands, **always** copy/paste the entire output verbatim and format it with [code fences](https://askubuntu.com/editing-help#code). When you translate terminal output in your own words or only post bits and pieces, this leaves out essential info. Similarly, when there is no formatting (not even line breaks), we can't tell apart commands and output from surrounding text.

Answer (score 0):

Once I learned that ALSA job is to detect the sound card. No card. well ok then. BIOS. that's embarrassing....

Alsamixer works great now the audio device is enabled.

Comment: Is the problem solved?  If so, thanks for your contribution. Would you mind [cleaning up your answer](https://askubuntu.com/posts/1376022/edit) a bit and telling us **exactly** what you did to solve the problem?  The solution here isn't very clear. If you can write out step-by-step what is needed to resolve your problem, it would be most helpful for future visitors. Our goal on Ask Ubuntu is to have a library of questions and answers about Ubuntu.  Maybe you can help someone else who has the same problem later.  https://askubuntu.com/tour

Comment: Thank you for guidance, I'm new to this. Once I learned enough to realize that ALSA is the software module responsible for detechting the hardware, I found the command INXA -SMA indicated no hardware. From there I went to the BIOS and found the device was disabled. Enabling the device in the BIOS and then updating Kubuntu, problem solved.

Comment: Please use the [edit](https://askubuntu.com/posts/1376022/edit) link to include the steps of the solution in your answer. (Not add comment)